# How to subtract the values in swift

Tags: swift

I want to subtract the `tex_length` and `dotPosition` values and I am getting error:

```
if let t = textField.text
 {            
    let dotPosition =  t.rangeOfString(".")?.endIndex.predecessor()
    let tex_length = countElements(textfield.text)
    print(dotPosition)
    print(tex_length)
    res = tex_length  - dotPosition ;           
 }
```

Comment: You seem to be using an outdated Xcode version, there is no countElements() function in the current Swift.

Comment: xcode 6.1.1 I am using

Comment: The current version is 7.3.1.

Comment: It would be nice if you had included the error but, if I have to guess, I'll guess that the two variables are different types.  Check that and, if it's the problem, convert one of them to the type you want to use.